# add a decimal place using re.sub with backreferences

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do an operation in python with re.sub but it isn't quite working out.

I thought something like this might work:

```
newstring = re.sub('\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]{7}\)','\1.\2', oldstring)
```

Where I create a decimal point in the number string that always has 7 numbers after the decimal. so as an example:

```
13871250 --> 1.3871250
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `newstring = re.sub(r'([0-9]*)([0-9]{7})',r'\1.\2', oldstring)` - remove escaping backslashes from the capturing parentheses and use raw string literals, especially with the replacement pattern.

Comment: How about a division by `10e7`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew that is perfect.  can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove escaping backslashes from the capturing parentheses (as the `\(` matches a *literal* `(`, same is with `\)` that matches `)` symbol) and use *raw string literals*, especially with the replacement pattern.

Use

```
newstring = re.sub(r'([0-9]*)([0-9]{7})',r'\1.\2', oldstring)
```